# Google Maps JS API: Better to store data in markers or in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am visualizing some government data using Google Maps JS API. Currently every time the user changes a filter value it grabs the entirety of the JSON data again, filters it, and creates a marker for each row that passes the filter validation. This is slow because it's re-downloading the JSON every time you change the form the filters are located in.

There are two ways to approach caching and displaying the data dynamically: storing the received JSON once and destroying/recreating markers based on the filter, or by creating all the markers at once and only displaying those that match filters.

Is there a performance difference between these two options? Both make sense to me, I'm just not sure how to tell whether one is better than the other. How can I assess how 'heavy' google maps markers are for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested 2 approaches are definitely going to be faster than the original strategy where the `JSON data` is re-fetched on each filter change.

I guess there are advantages and disadvantages to each method.

If you are not going to retrieve the `JSON data` on each filter change  then essentially the data could be `out of data` but if the use case is that the `JSON data` rarely gets updated then this consideration can be dropped.

Having the `JSON data` cached and creating all of the markers upfront would cause the map to take a bit longer than usual to load at start, as you will need to create all markers first whereas the other way round is that you only create a subset of the markers - hence quicker.

I guess it all comes down to how many markers are there? What is the typical using pattern of the map.

If there is a million markers and the typical filter would cause 100,000 markers to be regenerated on change, then you better off generating the  markers upfront and just tweak their visibility accordingly.

Similarly if you have a million markers and the typical filter would only cause 1 or 2 markers to appear out of the million, then probably destroying and recreate would be faster.

Anyway, as a user I would rather have the map take a bit longer to load at the start, probably sacrificing 1-2 seconds. Then have the markers changes instantaneously when I'm playing with the filters. Hope this helps.